# Why is my Gist not getting merged but creates a gistfile1.diff instead?

Tags: git, github

Somebody provided me with a Gist on Github that includes a small fix I want to include.
On my machine, which contains a clone of the Git repository where I want to apply the change to, I did the following:

```
git remote add fix [gisturl]

git merge fix/master
```

Now I have an additional file "gistfile1.diff" in my local repo but the changes in it were not applied to the target file.

```
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
 gistfile1.diff |   46 ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 1 file changed, 46 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 gistfile1.diff
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because that's not how you apply a diff stored in a gist. The gist itself is a repo, with each file in the gist as a separate file. The only way what you tried would work is if the repo is actually a fork of yours.

Instead you just want to download the diff file from the gist and pass it to `git apply`.